# Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected element type 'Array<String>.ArrayLiteralElement' (aka 'String')

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, firebase-authentication

A field in my firebase document is an array of strings which contains user ids.

When I try to initialise it in one of my views, I get the error
`Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected element type 'Array<String>.ArrayLiteralElement' (aka 'String')`

Here's what I am doing

```
@State var playerIds: [String] = [Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid, "SomeRandomHardcodedUserID"]
```

The line below works but the one mentioned above does not.

```
@State var playerIds: [String] = ["SomeHardcodedUID", "SomeOtherHardcodedUserID"]
```

My intention is to use `playerIds` to construct a codeable objet to send to Firestore.
The below line works with hardcoded userIds.

```
let newGame = Game(gameTime: gameTime, playerIds: playerIds, inProgress: gameInProgress, winnerId: winnerId)
```

What's the right way to go about putting current user's userId in my array?

Comment: `Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid` : It's a `String?`, ie an optional, so it can be nil. But you declared `playerIds` as `[String]`, so it can't contains optional values.

Comment: Yes indeed. I just figured that out and I have posted an answer as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out that the fix is to define the type of array as `[String?]` rather than `[String]`, which fixed my issue.
Passing `playerIds` as an argument was fixed by changing my `Game` structs model for `playerIds` to also use `[String?]` rather than `[String]`

Comment: `[String?]` is a pretty bad choice. What are you going to do with a missing/non-authorized user ID?

Comment: It probably is. I am working on improving the codebase to get rid of such stuff soon. Plan is to only use it as a temporary workaround.

Answer (score 1):

My issue with the same error was because I by mistake tried to add an array of elements into another array where one dimension array was expected. Will show the example.

```
func methodThetAxceptsTheArrayOfStrings(strings: [String]) {}

// Create the array
var arr1: [String] = []()

// call of the method
methodThetAxceptsTheArrayOfStrings(strings: [arr1]) // array without square brackets should be passed here. 

// call of the method with the correct parameter
methodThetAxceptsTheArrayOfStrings(strings: arr1)
```